# Custom Post Types - Taxonomy and Customization

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I'm trying to learn Custom Post Types and I have some questions. I'm trying to add a categories menu but that doesn't seem to be working for some reason - I don't get an error or anything. Here's my code, let me know if I should add in / improve on something:

```
// Create The Custom Post Type
function products_post_type(){
    register_post_type( 'generic_prodcts',
        array(
            'labels'    =>  array(
                'name'          =>  __( 'Products' ),
                'singular_name' =>  __( 'Product' ),
                'add_new_item'  =>  __('Add New Product'),
                'edit_item'     =>  __('Edit Product'),
                'search_items'  =>  __('Search Products')
            ),
            'public'        =>  true,
            'has_archive'   =>  true,
            'rewrite'       =>  array('slug' => 'products')
        )
    );
}
add_action( 'init', 'products_post_type' );

// Create The Columns
function generic_products_columns($columns){
    $columns = array(
        'check'     =>  '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title'     =>  __('Title',      'trans'),
        'desc'      =>  __('Description','trans'),
        'price'     =>  __('Price',      'trans'),
    );
    return $columns;
}
add_filter("manage_generic_prodcts_posts_columns", "generic_products_columns");

// Create The Column Data
function generic_products_column_data( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch ( $column ) {
        case "title":
            $title = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'title', true);
            echo '<a href="' . $title . '">' . $title. '</a>';
                break;
        case "desc":
            echo get_post_meta( $post_id, 'desc', true);
                break;
        case "price":
            $price = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'price', true);
            echo '<a href="' . $price . '">' . $price. '</a>';
                break;
    }
}
add_action( "manage_posts_custom_column", "generic_products_column_data");

// Make Post Type Columns Sortable
function generic_prodcts_sortable() {
  return array(
    'title' => 'Title',
    'desc'  => 'Description',
    'price' => 'Price'
  );
}
add_filter( "manage_edit-generic_prodcts_sortable_columns", "generic_prodcts_sortable" );

register_taxonomy(
    'Categories', 
    array('generic_products'), 
    array(
        'hierarchical'      => true, 
        'label'             => 'Categories',
        'singular_label'    => 'Category',
        'rewrite'           => true
    )
);
```

Also how do I go about customizing the custom post type page? Like I'd like to remove the text box and add in my own fields. I've tried googling it but I don't exactly know how to explain it to find decent results.

For reference, I've just been following:

[Yoast](http://yoast.com/custom-post-type-snippets/) and [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `taxonomies` argument to your registration array:

```
'taxonomies' => array('category')
```

That is:

```
    array(
        'labels'    =>  array(
            'name'          =>  __( 'Products' ),
            'singular_name' =>  __( 'Product' ),
            'add_new_item'  =>  __('Add New Product'),
            'edit_item'     =>  __('Edit Product'),
            'search_items'  =>  __('Search Products')
        ),
        'public'        =>  true,
        'has_archive'   =>  true,
        'rewrite'       =>  array('slug' => 'products'),
        'taxonomies' => array('category')
    )
```

## Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type